# Can't migrate foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

**UPDATE:** I'm going to abandon the foreign key stuff for now. Seems like my project is broken on a fundamental level so I'll revisit this project sometime later. I appreciate the two helpful lads in the comments.

I'm trying to encorporate foreign keys into my Laravel application but I just keep getting stuck. I keep getting `"errno: 150 "Foreign key constaint is incorrectly formed".`

Even after trying multiple solutions, deleting the table, changing migration order etc, I keep getting back to this error. It's extremely frustrating.

I have also tried `php artisan migrate:refresh` and `php artisan migrate:reset` but nothing seems to help.

In the code below there is a piece of code from the `CreateQuestionsTable class`

```
        Schema::table('questions', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('answerTypeName')->references('answerType')->on('answerstypes');
    });
```

I have tried to put this in the `CreateAnswersTable class` but that didn't solve it either.

In the code below there is another piece of code from the `CreateQuestionsTable class`

```
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('questionName');
        $table->string('answerTypeName');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here I also tried to change `answerTypeName` to `answerTypeId` with `$table->integer` but that also didn't help.

```
class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('questionName');
        $table->string('answerTypeName');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('questions', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('answerTypeName')->references('answerType')->on('answerstypes');
    });
}
}

class CreateAnswertypesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('answerstypes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('answerType');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


}
}
```

This is an error that keeps popping up

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `impact_dockwize`.`questions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

I expect it to work like this but the error keeps popping up when I try to do php artisan migrate. As I mentioned above, applying php artisan migrate:refresh or reset doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: in which order are you running the migrations? the `answerstypes` table has to be created before you can create a foreign key on your `questions` table.

Comment: @Remul the `answerstypes` table comes before the `questions` table.

Comment: I think I found the issue, a foreign key must either reference the primary key or a unique key of the parent table. If you add `$table->string('answerType')->unique();` it should work.

Comment: @Remul thanks for the suggestion! Sadly, it first returned an error that the table already existed, so I tried to remove the table. After running `php artisan migrate` again, I got back to the same error as in the original thread.

Comment: Did you remove the `migrations`, `questions` and `answerstypes` table manually  from the database and try to migrate again? I just tested your migrations locally myself and it works when I add `unique`.

Comment: @Remul I just tried to remove all those tables and ran `migrate:fresh`. Normal migrate gave me an error that the `user` table already existed. But yeah after running `migrate:fresh` I still got the error. I feel like my entire project is just broken right now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
Schema::table('questions', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->foreign('answerTypeName')->references('answerType')->on('answerstypes');
});
```

Remove it and leave it like this:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('questionName');
    $table->string('answerTypeName');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('answerTypeName')->references('answerType')->on('answerstypes');
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly it gives me another error back, `"SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'questions' already exists"` which is kinda of the cycle I've been experiencing for this entire afternoon already.

Comment: Try running it again with php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: Returns `"SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'questions' already exists"` again

Comment: That gave me back the initial error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'impact_dockwize'.'questions' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`. Didn't know that command existed tho

Comment: Why don't you reference an id instead of referencing an string? Try changing the reference: For exmple: 
  `$table->integer('answerTypeName_id');` and `$table->foreign('answerTypeName_id')->references('id')->on('answerstypes');`

Comment: Yeah I did do it like that in the beginning but that didn't change anything at the time sadly. Tried it just now and again, didn't help. Same error back. I honestly do not understand why it keeps throwing errors.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the effort you put into this! If all else fails I'll just not use foreign keys for now. I feel like my entire project is just fundamentally broken right now.